# How to go level up in file select window

Tags: macos, mac, open-directory

An application has the button to select folder. When I click it it opens a file/directory selection dialog.

[image]

- Is it possible to know the current path of directory I see in this dialog
- Is it possible to go one level up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the Path button, which shows all the levels up to the folder.

[image]
[image]

Click on a folder in this list to jump to it. The list is always reverse hierarchy so the folder containing the current folder will be one down from the top of the list.

The shortcut to go up a level is ⌘↑.